# roslaunch RRBOT doesn't work

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'm trying the example found [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros).
I cloned the gazebo_ros_demos in my /src.
I've no problems with

```
roslaunch rrbot_description rrbot_rviz.launch
```

But when I try to launch RRBot to Gazebo with :

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

it appears this on my screen:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [3477]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [3481]
process[urdf_spawner-3]: started with pid [3485]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 25, in <module>
    from gazebo_ros import gazebo_interface
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_ros/gazebo_interface.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gazebo_msgs.msg import *
ImportError: No module named msg
[ INFO] [1455036284.042904017]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1455036284.043749960]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been   advertised, waiting...
[urdf_spawner-3] process has died [pid 3485, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -urdf     -model rrbot -param robot_description __name:=urdf_spawner __log:=/home/gabriele/.ros/log/fd4ef6e0-cf48-11e5-a228-e839df8a64f0/urdf_spawner-3.log].
log file: /home/gabriele/.ros/log/fd4ef6e0-cf48-11e5-a228-e839df8a64f0/urdf_spawner-3*.log
```

Gazebo starts, but rrbot doesn't appear neither in the world, nor in the model database.
I'm not able to understand if the error is in the file (like rrbot_world.launch, rrbot.world) or if I forgot to insert something in the bashrc file.

What am I missing here?

Bye

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12550/roslaunch-rrbot-doesn%27t-work/) by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the problem. There was a compatibility problem: replacing mi 6.5 version of gazebo with the 5.2 version the problem disappears.

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) with karma: 19 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longforgotten](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1313/longforgotten/) on 2016-02-19**:
Glad to know this :)
As you solved the problem, you can close the question.